# Start a .cpp file from another .cpp file

Tags: c++, function

i have tried everything on google and duckduckgo. i just gave up and came to you to ask a question.

im working on a project for learning CPP and got into a problem. I got 2 files.

One called: Nudle.cpp (the main one)

```cpp
// Nudle.cpp : This file contains the 'main' function. Program execution begins and ends there.
#include <fstream>
#include <iostream>
#include "PasGen.cpp"
#include "PasGen.h"
using namespace std;

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    int choice;

    do {
        cout << "NUDLE Menu\n";
        cout << "Please make your selection\n";
        cout << "   1 - Generate password\n";
        cout << "   2 - View Saved Passwords\n";
        cout << "   3 - Quit\n";
        cout << "Selection = ";
        cin >> choice;

        switch (choice) {
        case 1:
            break;
        case 2:
            cout << "????\n";
            break;
        case 3:
            cout << "Goodbye!";
            break;
        default:
            cout << endl << endl << "Main Menu\n";
            cout << "Please make your selection\n";
            cout << "   1 - Start game\n";
            cout << "   2 - Options\n";
            cout << "   3 - Quit\n";
            cout << "Selection = ";
            cin >> choice;
        }
    } while (choice != 3);
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
```

and one called PasGen.cpp ( a password generator )

```cpp
#include<iostream>
#include<cstdlib> 
#include<ctime> 
using namespace std;
static const char alphnum[] = "0123456789" "!@#$%^&*" "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ" "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz";
int strLen = sizeof(alphnum) - 1;
char GenRand()
{
    return alphnum[rand() % strLen];
}
int PassGen()
{
    int n, c = 0, s = 0;
    srand(time(0));
    cout << "Enter the length of the password required:";
    cin >> n;
    cout << n << endl;
    cout << "Your Password is:";
N:
    char C;
    string D;
    for (int z = 0; z < n; z++)
    {
        C = GenRand();
        D += C;
        if (isdigit(C))
        {
            c++;
        }
        if (C == '!' || C == '@' || C == '$' || C == '%' || C == '^' || C == '&' || C == '*' || C == '#')
        {
            s++;
        }
    }
    if (n > 2 && (s == 0 || c == 0))
    {
        goto N;
    }
    cout << D;
}
```

and i just cant figure out how do i make the Nudle start PasGen after a person requests for the 
*Password Generator*

And i want it to show the output to the same console, not open a new one.

Admins please dont close my Thread if it already exists. i have been nearly all treads and still cant understand

Comment: You need to read more. Read about header files and function prototypes. J would suggest following some C++ tutorials.

Comment: This doesn't address the question, but get rid of that `goto`. Pretend that `goto` doesn't exist. Replace it with `do { ... } while (n > 2 && (s == 0 || c == 0))`. That does the same thing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are some issues in your main.cpp file. The biggest one is that you included the cpp file in another cpp file. How normally this should work is that you compile both cpp files separately and then link them together to create the final output.

So I commented out the following (by adding a leading //)

```
#include "PasGen.cpp"
```

Then I have to include the cstdlib, because you are using EXIT_SUCCESS

```
#include <cstdlib>
```

Finally I am able to call the function in your case 1

```
case 1:
        PassGen();
        break;
```

And After all these changes I can compile both files separately and link them together

```
 g++ -c main.cpp
 g++ -c PasGen.cpp
 g++ main.o PasGen.o
```

And then run it

```
$ ./a.exe
NUDLE Menu
Please make your selection
   1 - Generate password
   2 - View Saved Passwords
   3 - Quit
Selection = 1
Enter the length of the password required:10
10
Your Password is:N0sJ%YphnFNUDLE Menu
```

You can also compile both files together

```
g++ main.cpp PasGen.cpp
```

which will eventually do the same thing but its better to have the concepts straight from the start.